# Export Project SDK Settings in Intellij Idea 13.1

Tags: intellij-idea, settings, intellij-13

I need to export my Project SDK (to JDK 1.7) settings. What is the category that needs to be exported to accomplish this.

I was able to export SDK tables, but was not able to export the setting, that changed the project level SDK.